# Symfony how to store many objects

Tags: object, symfony1

in my symfony application there's a form to fill out and submit with ajax (the user can submit many times). 
When the user submits the form, I would like to store the object somewhere (to save in the database later) and I was wondering where is the right place!
can anyone help me??
tnx
Jury D'ambros

Comment: Why not save it directly to the database? Is there a final submit, that would be used to save all the objects at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer really is saving the object to the database and maybe have a column in that table that flags the object as temporary.

Another approach could be saving the object to the user's attribute holder:

```
$object = new YourObject();

// deal with the form bind here
// ...
// i is an integer so you may have different attributes
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('ObjectName-'.i, $object);
```

Comment: i choose the second approach, i made an array of objects and i have saved it as user attribute!